# What is the proper JavaScript object format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made an exercise about `ng-repeat` with AngularJS 1.x , everything goes well.

**JavaScript**:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('myController', function() {
  this.dishes = [
    {
      'name': 'CD',
      'drink': 'wine',
      'color': 'red'
    },
    {
      name: 'vagetable',
      drink: 'water',
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      'name': 'meat',
      'drink': 'coffee',
      'color': 'brown'
    }
  ];
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">

<head></head>

<body ng-controller="myController as myCtrl">
  <div> {{myController.dishes}} </div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="dish in myCtrl.dishes">
      <p> {{dish.name}} is my name.</p>
      <p> {{dish.drink}} is something you can drink.</p>
      <p> {{dish.color}} is the color I wear.</p>
      <hr>
    </li>
    <p> {{myCtrl.theModelContent}}</p>
    <input type='text' ng-model="myCtrl.theModelContent">
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I noticed that `'name': 'CD'` works fine as well as `name: 'vegetable'`. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: The json key can be like `key:value`,`'key':value`,`"key":value`

Comment: @YingYi except that `key:value` and `'key':value` is not json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a wire format where everything is a string, thus the usual call of JSON.stringify for your JavaScript object literal. Whereas JavaScript object literals can have string or non-string keys. The short answer is having a string key in a JavaScript object literal is optional, while it is required in the JSON-formatted version of that object literal.